# A question about oauth2.0 client_secret when exchanging authorization code for token

Tags: oauth-2.0

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3
"""
The client makes a request to the token endpoint by sending the
following parameters using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
format per Appendix B with a character encoding of UTF-8 in the HTTP
request entity-body:

grant_type
REQUIRED.  Value MUST be set to "authorization_code".

code
REQUIRED.  The authorization code received from the
authorization server.

redirect_uri
REQUIRED, if the "redirect_uri" parameter was included in the
authorization request as described in Section 4.1.1, and their
values MUST be identical.

client_id
REQUIRED, if the client is not authenticating with the
authorization server as described in Section 3.2.1.

If the client type is confidential or the client was issued client
credentials (or assigned other authentication requirements), the
client MUST authenticate with the authorization server as described
in Section 3.2.1.
"""

client_secret is not in the param list, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If client type is public than client secret does not exist. Read section 3.2.1 and then section 2.1.

> Confidential clients are typically issued (or establish) a set of
> client credentials used for authenticating with the authorization
> server (e.g., password, public/private key pair).

So for confidential clients one more parameter is required. In Keycloak or IdentityServer4 that parameter is client_secret.